# Replicate natural conditions for plant

Tags: sunlight, greenhouse, ficus

I am having a plant that according to my research requires a lot of light but it does not do well in direct sunlight. I am trying to recreate these conditions in an artificial setting (think greenhouse without any natural light).

I was wondering what exactly could be the part that the plant dislikes about the direct sunlight. I can think of two issues, one is one of the UV immissions the other is the heat from the sun.

I was wondering if anyone knows the answer to that so I can properly tune my indoor lighting for that plant. The plant I am talking about is Ficus Lyrata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ficus lyrata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_lyrata) is native to West Africa where it grows up to 15 meters tall. It can be grown outside in Florida.
[image: Ficus lyrata in Florida]
(Courtesy of commons.wikimedia.org)

It is not more sensitive to UV or heat than any other tropical plant.

[What it is sensitive to is dramatic changes in light levels.](https://www.velux.com/what-we-do/research-and-knowledge/deic-basic-book/daylight/daylight-calculations-and-measurements)  Outside light levels can be 100,000 lux.  Inside a room away from a window can be 200 lux.  When you move a plant inside or outside it needs time adjust to the new light levels and the usual response is dropping leaves.

To grow them indoors provide lots of overhead light.  Fluorescents, LED, halogen, whatever you have but lots of it.  Get a light meter to test the light levels.

- Ficus lyrata can be propagated in any soil less mix.
- Ensure your
  cuttings have at least three nodes and use a rooting hormone for
  woody plants.
- Increase the humidity with a bag over the cuttings
- Consider cutting the leaves in half crosswise to reduce moisture loss
- Most cuttings root in four to six weeks